# Compare groups for incomplete cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with some incomplete records, for example:

```py
    fname lname   loc   
0     a      z    UK      
1     b      k    USA     
2     a      z            
3     c      p    DE      
4     a      z    EU      
5     b      k            
6     b      k            
7     a      z    ENG     
8     c      p    DE
```

For each pair of fname and lname, I want to compare missing loc with other existing loc. Therefore, I used a groupby function to first group similar fname and lname into a pair and assign each a group number.

```py
    fname lname   loc   ngroup
0     a      z    UK      0
1     b      k    USA     1
2     a      z            0
3     c      p    DE      2
4     a      z    EU      0
5     b      k            1
6     b      k            1
7     a      z    ENG     0
8     c      p    DE      2
```

Now there are groups that are complete, such as ngroup 2 where we have loc value for all the pairs of fname and lname. But the other groups, 0 and 1 have missing or conflicting values for loc. My interest is to compare each of these groups in a large dataframe for inconsistencies and further imputations.

Is there a way to filter the dataframe for only the blank loc groups and skip the complete groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
>>> df.groupby(["fname", "lname"]).filter(lambda gr: gr["loc"].eq("").any())

  fname lname  loc
0     a     z   UK
1     b     k  USA
2     a     z
4     a     z   EU
5     b     k
6     b     k
7     a     z  ENG
```

For each group, this keeps only those that have their `loc` column `eq`ual to `""` i.e., empty string for `any` of the rows.

Comment: I appreciate your solution but i would like to get the opposite, that is to get fname and lname with blank values for loc. Your code filters the non-missing loc groups and returns the filled loc groups.

Comment: @Hanif I see, sorry. Changed the operation to `eq("").any()` so it keeps those that have a blank `loc` at any row.